# hibernate criteria sqlRestriction

Tags: hibernate, criteria, restrictions

I have:

```
criteria.createAlias(withAlias(alias, PLAN_PROPERTY), PLAN_ALIAS)
                    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty(withAlias(alias, "course"), withAlias(PLAN_ALIAS, "years")));
```

where `course` is integer, `years` is float.
Need to do `FLOOR()` on the `years` property. `alias` is the current entity alias.

I would like to do this with Restrictions.sqlRestriction() like this:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias1}.course = FLOOR({alias2}.years)")
```

but we can use only the keyword `{alias}` that is processed by hibernate and returns the current criteria root entity alias. **How to do this with two different aliases of inner join tables?**